# Facebook login. Not only for me, but for all who visit my website

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I have setup facebook login on my website that i am working on.

I used this to get it working.
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/getting-started/

Now when i login with my facebook accout, everything works fine.

But when i try to login with another facebook account, i get the following error

**An error occurred. Please try again later**

I want to make my webiste accessible to all and not only me.
Is there something that i am missing here ???

Thanks

Comment: Did you change sandbox mode to OFF?

Comment: yes sandbox mode is disabled. Should it be enabled ?

Comment: yes, its disabled then.

Comment: It working now. I changed sandbox mode to "enabled" and saved changes. Then again changed sandbox mode to "disable" and saved the changes. It somehow worked. Thanks a lot Damonsson :)

Comment: Facebook... it's normally ;)